# PHP string concatenation with WordPress custom post fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a string in my WordPress site using fields from the post so that I can use that string to later run a script however I am having a hard time getting the string to properly concat. Here is my loop that I'm running:

```
<?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'products',
        'category_name'  => $post_type
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();  ?>

    <div class="cell small-12 medium-6 large-3 product-cell text-center">
        <div data-shopify-product="<?php the_field('product_id'); ?>"></div>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><button class="button large productDetailsButton">Details</button></a>
        <div id="category-snippet-<?php the_field('product_id'); ?>"></div>
    </div>
    <?php 
        $powerReviewsScript = $powerReviewsScript . "
        {
            locale: 'en_US',
            merchant_group_id: 79052,
            page_id: '" . the_field('product_id') . "',
            merchant_id: 127395,
            api_key: '0d462e35-0345-4511-859e-03b0a65aea6d',
            review_wrapper_url: 'http://yoursite.com/write-a-review/?pr_page_id=" . the_field('product_id') . "',
            components: {
                CategorySnippet: 'category-snippet-" . the_field('product_id') . "'
            }
        },"
    ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

The problem I am running into is 2-fold:
1. The PHP is not injecting `the_field('product_id')` into the string. It is showing up as empty

 2. `the_field('product_id')` gets printed to the HTL every time it is called in the PHP.

Am I forming this string incorrectly? Is it possible to create a string in this fashion?

Comment: did you try using `get_field` instead inside of your concatenation?

Comment: @disinfor ...... -_- I'm really dumb. Thank you. I've been staring at this for way too long trying to figure out what I was doing wrong

Comment: We've all been there :)